# Strange Tor browser bug

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, connection, tor-network

When starting up the Tor browser, I got a message saying:

[image]

That wasn't an issue, I've gotten this message before and I just have to close Tor browser and open it up again and it would fix. However, when I went to https://check.torproject.org to confirm that Tor wasn't working, I got this:

[image]

which really confused me. So either the browser was giving the false message or the website was giving the false message though I strongly suspected it was the browser. I also checked if I could access a hidden service and I could:

[image]

From this I understood that the Tor browser was giving an incorrect message and that Tor was working. I was even able to see my circuit when reaching Facebook's onion service:

[image]

So I was certain that Tor was working by now. With this information, I have a few questions:

- Do I report this bug to the Tor project's Gitlab or has this already been reported and is being fixed?
- If possible to answer, why is this even happening?
- Can I change the Tor browser manually to fix this?
- Any other information on this would be helpful so I could understand the problem better.

When this bug occured, I was using Windows 10 OS instead of Linux (I usually use Linux, but I didn't use it at the moment). If you guys need anymore information about my device, just comment below and I will edit this post to add the information. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I report this bug to the Tor project's Gitlab or has this already been reported and is being fixed?

It has been reported before: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/torbutton/-/issues/23918, but you may want to comment on it since it seems dead (I can also do it if you want me to)

> If possible to answer, why is this even happening?

I don't know. Something in how Tor Browser checks for connectivity went wrong.

> Can I change the Tor browser manually to fix this?

I don't know what you would need to change, rather I suggest you report it so that it can be fixed for everyone and fixed by people that understand Tor Browser.

Comment: can you comment on the issue and add the link to this post because I can't do it yet. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: There is this one issue: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/torbutton/-/issues/40028 you aren't using alpha are you @Swangie?

Comment: no I am not using the Alpha version of Tor browser.